# Fastest way to sort and swap elements in Java

Tags: java, swap, quicksort, bubble-sort

In Java, I have a list of positive different numbers.

Each number is used as a key in hashsets `IntIntHashSet fs` and `cs` used in code below to retrieve some condition values.
Then I check the condition (if statement) and if true, swap the elements.

```
int[] list = // given list of positive different ints like [14, 2, 7, 19, 20, 3]
int l = list.length;
if (l > 1) {
    int elI, elJ, fI, fJ, swap;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        boolean swapped = false;
        for (int j = 1; j < l; j++) {
            elI = list[j - 1];
            elJ = list[j];
            fI = fs.get(elI);
            fJ = fs.get(elJ);
            if (fI > fJ || (fI == fJ && cs.get(elI) > cs.get(elJ))) {
                swap = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j - 1];
                list[j - 1] = swap;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!swapped) break;
    }
}
```

It looks like a *Bubble* sort, though I'm not very sure. I'm writing a time-consuming program and this part should be optimized as well as possible.

The **main question**: will it be faster to use another sorting approach like *QuickSort*?

Second question: will it be faster to use **xor** swap method without a temporary variable `swap`?

**[EDIT]**: I might have a very long list containing thousands of numbers. The one above is simple due to example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for partial sorted array and small set of data, bubble sort would be efficient way. quicksort would be efficient only for large(huge) sets of data. you seem to be implementing bubble sort, which would be sufficient for small sets of data.

check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for efficiency for different sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

With Java, you don't know until you benchmarked and profiled it extensively.

Some code that works well for small sets might work worse for larger sets and the other way around. Depending on when it is optimized, and with which preconditions. It may recognize the way XOR can be encoded efficiently in machine code, or it may encode this differently.
It might even vary between client and server VM.

As a matter of fact, the `sort` method for collections in Java was replaced from JDK 6 to JDK 7 (from IIRC Quicksort to TimSort, a hybrid in-place mergesort coming from Python IIRC).

Just these days I've been fighting a situation where one could logically just *must* be faster, but any benchmark showed the opposite, which can only be explained by JIT optimization being executed differently due to different hotspots. And the less efficient code apparently triggered a better optimization.